# General form of Nullstellensatz

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

At lots of places (some examples are [1](https://mathoverflow.net/a/15231/43380), [2](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ejpbell/nullstellensatz.pdf), [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_ring)), it is stated, that Hilbert's Nullstellensatz is well understood as theorem about more general Jacobson rings. Namely

*(When $R$ is a Jacobson ring and $S$ finitely generated $R$-algebra, then $S$ is also Jacobson.) If $M$ is a maximal ideal of $S$, then the pullback ideal $N=M\cap R$ of $R$ is also maximal and the field $S/M$ is finite extension over the field $R/N$.*

Why is this considered to be generalize Nullstellensatz? Isn't that mainly a statement about restrictions for existence of solutions, or more precise characterization of the Galois connection in question.

The general version statement is in my opinion analogous to [Zariski's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski%27s_lemma), which is used in the first step of the usual Nullstellensatz' proof.

It's very well possible it's called Nullstellensatz even though the analogy is not a strong one, because the Zariski's lemma is the crucial ingredient in the proof. However, I'm not writing here to rant about the name. I want to make sure I'm not missing something: Are the other parts of Nullstellensatz deducible from the general form or is there more to the theory of Jacobson rings, that would generalize the usual case?

Comment: Have you really used the full strength of the first part? I think that's what gets you to the $I(Z(\mathfrak a)) = \sqrt{\mathfrak a}$.

Comment: @Hoot What do you mean by “the first part”? I think that a proof of [“a finitely generated algebra over a Jacobson ring is Jacobson” $\Rightarrow$ $I(V(\mathfrak{a}))=\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}$] may not be possible. The finitely generated $k$-algebra $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is always a Jacobson ring for an arbitrary field $k$, since fields are Jacobson. On the other hand, the result $I(V(\mathfrak{a}))=\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}$ is only true when $\overline{k}=k$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the *classical Nullstellensatz* in $k[x_1, \dotsc, x_n]$ states $$\sqrt{\mathfrak a} = \mathcal I(\mathcal V(\mathfrak a)) = \bigcap\limits_{\mathfrak a \subset \mathfrak m} \mathfrak m,$$ with the intersection being taken over all maximal ideals containing $\mathfrak a$.

In any ring, we have a *formal Nullstellensatz*: $$\sqrt{\mathfrak a} = \bigcap\limits_{\mathfrak a \subset \mathfrak p} \mathfrak p,$$
with the intersection being taken over all prime ideals containing $\mathfrak a$. Note that the most proofs of this fact are actually modern versions of the Rabinowitsch trick (Rabinowitsch trick is just localizing, not so tricky from the modern point of view ;) ).

In a Jacobson ring, we have $\bigcap\limits_{\mathfrak a \subset \mathfrak p} \mathfrak p = \bigcap\limits_{\mathfrak a \subset \mathfrak m} \mathfrak m$, i.e. the formal Nullstellensatz boils down to the formulation of the classical Nullstellensatz. This is why a result about many rings being Jacobson is called a generalization of the Nullstellensatz.

Comment: Thanks! I was almost aware of that. I have proved $\cal{I}(\cal{V}(\mathfrak{a})) = \bigcap_{\mathfrak{a} \subseteq \mathfrak{m}}\mathfrak{m}$, but haven't realized this must be equal to $\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}$. I know an elementary proof of the *formal Nullstellensatz* via Zorn's lemma. Is that the modern version of Rabinowitch? Because no explicit localization is used in it - and if implicit I don't know where and how :)

Comment: To be more precise: I've proved, that $k[x_1, \dotsc, x_n]$ is Jacobson from the fact that $\cal{I}(\cal{V}(\mathfrak{a}))=\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}$. That is, I believe, the *strong Nullstellensatz*. It's fun to see it's doable the other way around as well.

Comment: @liczman The proof you are maybe referring to is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/732937/394668).

Answer (score 1):

$\def\bbA{\mathbb{A}}
\def\fra{\mathfrak{a}}
\def\jn{\operatorname{JN}}
\def\an{\operatorname{AN}}
\def\frm{\mathfrak{m}}$Let's call the statement in italics from the OP the *Jacobson Nullstellensatz*, and abbreviate it as $\jn(R,S)$, for a given Jacobson ring $R$ and a finitely generated $R$-algebra $S$.

Let $k$ be any field, and denote $\bbA_k^n=k^n$ to the $n$-dimensional classical affine space over $k$. For each subset $S\subset k[T_1,\dots,T_n]$, denote $V(S)=\{x\in\bbA_k^n\mid f(x)=0,\;\forall f\in S\}$ to the vanishing set of $S$. On the other hand, for each subset $X\subset\bbA_k^n$, denote $I(X)=\{f\in k[T_1,\dots,T_n]\mid f(x)=0,\;\forall x\in X\}$ to the vanishing polynomial ideal of $X$. Then, for any ideal $\fra\subset k[T_1,\dots,T_n]$, it is not difficult to verify that $I(V(\fra))\supset\sqrt{\fra}$.

Now suppose that $k$ is algebraically closed field (we will assume so for the rest of the post). Then it holds that $I(V(\fra))=\sqrt{\fra}$. Let's call *algebraic Nullstellensatz* to this assertion, and abbreviate it as $\an$.

I claim that
$$
\jn(k,k[T_1,\dots,T_n])\iff\an.
$$
Note: of course this equivalence is just a tautology, these assertions are true mathematical statements by their own right. What I actually mean with this logic equation is that there is a direct proof of each of the claims using the other one. This justifies why it makes sense to call $\jn(R,S)$ the “general form of the Nullstellensatz” (as they do in the links 2, 3 from the OP).

Let's give the argument. We start with an easy

> **Lemma.** Let $K$ be any field (algebraically closed or not), and let $x\in\bbA_K^n$. Then $I(\{x\})=(T_1-x_1,\dots,T_n-x_n)$.

*Proof.* The ideal $(T_1-x_1,\dots,T_n-x_n)$ is maximal, for $K[T_1,\dots,T_n]/(T_1-x_1,\dots,T_n-x_n)\cong K$. On the other hand, this ideal it is contained in the proper ideal $I(\{x\})$, so they must be the same ideal. $\square$

$(\Leftarrow)$ [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/732937/394668) it is proven that $k[T_1,\dots,T_n]$ is a Jacobson ring using $\an$. On the other hand, let $\frm\subset k[T_1,\dots,T_n]$ be a maximal ideal. Then $k\cap\frm=(0)$ is maximal in $k$, and it remains to show that $k[T_1,\dots,T_n]/\frm$ is a finite field extension of $k$. It suffices to show that there is $x\in\bbA_k^n$ with $\frm=(T_1-x_1,\dots,T_n-x_n)$. On the one hand, since $V(I(X))=\overline{X}$ for any subset $X\subset\bbA^n_k$ (true regardless of the algebraic closedness of $k$, see [GW], Prop. 1.12(2)), $\an$ implies that the operators $I(-),V(-)$ are the mutual inverses of a contravariant isomorphism between the posets of Zariski closed subsets of $\bbA_k^n$ and radical ideals of $k[T_1,\dots,T_n]$. In particular, the [atoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(order_theory)) in the Zariski closed subsets are the points. Thus, $\frm$, which is a coatom in the poset of radical ideals of $k[T_1,\dots,T_n]$, must be of the form $\frm=I(\{x\})=(T_1-x_1,\dots,T_n-x_n)$, for some $x\in\bbA_k^n$ (where the last equality is our lemma).

$(\Rightarrow)$ This is basically what [GW] does. There $\jn(k,A)$ is Theorem 1.7 and $\an$ is Prop. 1.12(1). With the objective to be self-contained, we reproduce the proof here. Assume $\jn(k,A=k[T_1,\dots,T_n])$. In particular, for a maximal ideal $\frm\subset A$, the field $A/\frm$ is a finite field extension of $k$ via the composite $k\to A\to A/\frm$. Since the finite field extensions of an algebraically closed field are all trivial, this map is an isomorphism.

(The following is taken from [GW], hoping this qualifies as fair use.)
[image]

Our lemma says that $\frm_x=I(\{x\})$, for $x\in\bbA_k^n$. Hence, for $Z\subset\bbA_k^n$, we have
[image]

[image]
In the middle equality we've used Corollary 1.11(2). The last equality is the fact that $k[T_1,\dots,T_n]$ is Jacobson. $\square$

---

### References

[GW] U. Görtz, T. Wedhorn, *Algebraic Geometry I: Schemes*. Second ed. Springer Spektrum.