# Why radical of an ideal is contained in all maximal ideals containing this ideal?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

I would like to ask about the relation $$\sqrt{I} \subseteq \bigcap_{\text{maximal } m \supseteq I} m$$

regarding ring $k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$, where $k$ is an arbitrary field and $I$ is a proper ideal in this polynomial ring. Based on the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732907/intersection-of-all-maximal-ideals-containing-a-given-ideal) I assume that should always hold. However I don't see why for an arbitrary maximal ideal $m \supseteq I$ one would obtain inclusion $\sqrt{I}\subseteq m.$

Thus, why $\sqrt{I}\subseteq m$ for arbitrary maximal ideal $m \supseteq I$?

Comment: It follows from the fact that $m$ is prime.

Comment: ... and from the definition of the *radical* of an ideal.  One property of the radical of an ideal is that it is the intersection of all prime ideals that contain it.  The intersection of all maximal ideals that contain it is called the *Jacobson radical*.

Comment: @MarkSaving Yeah, that will do. Thanks :D